After deploying my python script using GAE, the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_openai'" always appears when running
After deploying my Python script using Google App Engine (GAE), I encounter the following error whenever I run the application: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_openai' . ( /workspace/line-traffic-bot-O.py:38 ).
Below is the import section of my script:
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import os
import pytz
from typing import List, Tuple

from google.cloud import firestore

from linebot.v3 import (
    WebhookHandler
)
from linebot.v3.exceptions import (
    InvalidSignatureError
)
from linebot.v3.messaging import (
    Configuration,
    ApiClient,
    MessagingApi,
    ReplyMessageRequest,
    TextMessage,
    ShowLoadingAnimationRequest,
)
from linebot.v3.webhooks import (
    MessageEvent,
    TextMessageContent,
    UserSource,
    RoomSource,
    GroupSource
)

from langchain.callbacks.tracers import ConsoleCallbackHandler
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from langchain_core.runnables import (
    RunnableParallel,
)
from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from zep_cloud.client import Zep
from zep_cloud.langchain import ZepChatMessageHistory
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Firestore 初始化
db = firestore.Client()
load_dotenv()

#設定金鑰環境變數
ZEP_API_KEY = os.environ.get("ZEP_API_KEY")
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
PINECONE_API_KEY = os.environ.get("PINECONE_API_KEY")

#初始化 Zep Cloud

Here is my requirements.txt file:
gunicorn
Flask==3.0.3
pytz==2023.3.post1
google-api-core==2.19.0
google-auth==2.29.0
google-cloud-core==2.4.1
google-cloud-firestore==2.16.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.63.0
line-bot-sdk==3.11.0
requests==2.31.0
langchain==0.2.3
langchain-community==0.2.4
langchain-core==0.2.5
langchain-openai==0.1.8
langchain-pinecone==0.1.1
zep-cloud==1.0.4

Here is my app.yaml file:
service: traffictest
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT line-traffic-bot-O:app
env_variables:
  CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN: ExxxxxxxxxxxxxxH+nJObFnA+ZkOedPURmE0CMhNAdB04t89/1O/w1cDnyilFU=
  CHANNEL_SECRET: 22caxxxxxxxxxxxx
  PINECONE_API_KEY: c0ebxxxxxxxxxxx
  OPENAI_API_KEY: sk-bqZCcFtxxxxxxxxxxx
  ZEP_API_KEY: z_1dWlkIxxxxxxxxxxx

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto

readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 10
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 5
  success_threshold: 1

liveness_check:
  path: "/_ah/health"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps, but none have resolved the issue:
Installing only the langchain package in requirements.txt.
Installing langchain along with langchain-openai.
Switching the Python runtime version to 3.11.
Despite these attempts, the ModuleNotFoundError persists. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.
